# Get json data and display in div using jquery in my Popup

Tags: jquery

In my button click i had a popup div and inside that i need to show divs with  data return in json format

```
      <a href='somelink' title='hello'class='details' rel='id'>h1</a>
```

My pop up div as follows

```
<div id="popupdiv">
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".details").live("click", function () {
     var id = $(this).attr("rel");

    $('#popupdiv').modal();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            url: "/mycontroller/details?Id="+ id,
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { //which contains name,email etc how can i append the  details on to the "popupdiv" div by inserting in to another div

            }
    });
    return false;                     
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? use like: alert(data.name);

Comment: not showing alert frnd i need to fill the name etc on to a div and then that to be added on to parent div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the returned data to the div you are using as a modal. Here is an example for "name":

```
success: function (data) { 
    $('#popupdiv').append(data.name);
}
```

If you want a div within #popupdiv, use

```
success: function (data) { 
    $('#popupdiv').append('<div id="innerPopupDiv"></div>');
    $('#innerPopupDiv').append(data.name);
}
```

http://jqapi.com/#p=append

Note that I've taken a guess at what your JSON is like.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function (data) {
  $("<div>").appendTo("#popupdiv").append(data.name);
}
```

Comment: thaks all for ur valuable answers

Answer (score 1):

Have you used tmpl before?

I would use tmpl to render the content into your div.

Firstly create a template

```
<script id="messageTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<span>${Message}</span>
</script>
```

then in the success function render the template to the div.

```
    $("#popupdiv").empty();
    $("#messageTemplate").tmpl(results).appendTo("#popupdiv");
```

then do a $("#popupdiv").dialog().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) shortcut of `$.ajax` with `dataType:json` like this:

```
$.getJSON(url: "/mycontroller/details?Id=" + id, function(data) {
    var names = [];
    var emails = [];
    for (var i = 0, result = data; i < result.length; i++) {
       names.push(result[i].name);
       emails.push(result[i].email);
    }

    $('#popupdiv').html(names.join('') + '<br />' + email.join(''));
});
```

Comment: its not list of data my frnd just data of one client

Comment: @SreenathPlakkat: You should post an example of how your data looks. You said data contains names, emails, etc.

Comment: In my controller                                                        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult details(int Id)
        {
            using(var _session=MvcApplication.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                var data = _session.CreateCriteria<usertable>()
                         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", Id)).UniqueResult<usertable>();

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
          
        } where data.name=sreenath; data.url=www.google.com; etc